# Why aren't all these verbs in the same tense?

Tags: past-tense, past-vs-present-perfect

> We have decided to call it a day.  We are thankful for everyone that has come to our shows, screamed at the top of their lungs, bought our music, wore our tee shirt and joined the spirit of the band in the pit.

“has come to our shows” is an experience present perfect (even if there won't be any more shows as the band is going to split soon, so I think that past simple could be fine too as the other verbs should be in past simple (*screamed*, *wore*, *bought*, *joined*).

My question is in fact why present perfect for the first verb and past simple for the others, would it be better to put all these verbs either past simple or present perfect (all of them could be considered as life experience)

https://twitter.com/flying_vinyl springking 20 nov

Comment: The simple past is specific about when the decision was made, the other merely tells us the decision was made in the past. The has here means"has come, has screamed, has bought and has worn and has joined. They are all PP. And wore is a mistake.

Comment: ok but what made me think it was past simple is wore instead of worn

Answer (score 1):

They're all in the perfect tense.  In English it's fine to omit a repeating word, especially on Twitter with its character limit

So the tweeter could have written:

> We are thankful for everyone that **has** come to our shows, **has** screamed at the top of their lungs, **has** bought our music, **has** wore our tee shirt and **has** joined the spirit of the band in the pit.

but in this context there's no reason for it.

Comment: I'm sure "has wore" exists in some non-standard Englishes, but not in any standard English I am aware of.

Comment: There's a number of irregular past/past participle forms that are often transposed in spoken English.  It's incorrect but common.  The speaker probably intended *has worn*.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a mistake.

I think the writer started with the perfect, ("has come") and continued with perfect forms which are also the simple past ("[has] screamed", "[has] bought"), and by then had forgotten that these were perfect and not simple past, and so wrote "wore" instead of "worn".

Comment: could the writer have used past simple  as the decision was taken to split and therefore belongs now to the past, even if the band has not really  split at the time of  of writing

Comment: It's possible, @user5577. It reads very awkwardly in that case. I think it is a mistake.

Comment: Yes, that's right, the writer forgot and used **wore** instead of worn. I personally do not think one can read the sentence in full as having "switched" to simple past. That is not coherent with the rest of the phrasing. This is Twitter and not edited prose. Their social media person (or whatever those people are called) did not catch it. Or a band member wrote it himself.

Comment: when I said past simple, in my mind  It was for all verbs (came, screamed, bought , wore and joined would it be possible

Comment: @user5577 Why not just chose Colin's answer? I dislike it when a perfectly good answer is given, the original poster does not select it and then it gets re-opened. Such a bore.